# Is it necessary to remove an entity from the collection on the inverse side, if its parent's reference is set to null in the entity while merging?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, eclipselink

Inverse side (Department) :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(0);
```

Owning side (Employee) :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Department department;
```

The method that merges an `Employee` entity supplied by a client having a null `Department` in it :

```
public Employee update(Employee employee) {
    Department department = employee.getDepartment();

    if (department == null) {
        Employee managedEmployee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employee.getEmployeeId());
        // Obtain the original Employee entity which may still have its Department intact.

        if (managedEmployee == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        Department managedDepartment = managedEmployee.getDepartment();

        if (managedDepartment != null) {
            managedEmployee.getDepartment().getEmployeeList().remove(managedEmployee);
            // Removing an Employee entity from the list on the inverse side,
            // since it will no longer be pointing to Employee after Employee is merged.
        }

        return entityManager.merge(employee);
    }
}
```

The supplied `Employee` is a detached entity. Suppose that `Department` is optional for `Employee`s and hence, there is a null foreign key (`ON DELETE SET NULL`).

Is it necessary to explicitly remove an `Employee` entity as shown in the `update()` method above from the employee list on the inverse side of the relationship (`Department`), when the supplied `Employee` does not contain a  `Department` (because it has already been set to null by the client while editing the `Employee` entity) before merging the supplied `Employee` entity?

I think, the provider will keep, the `Employee` reference in the list of employees on the inverse side of the relationship, on dangling otherwise.

<sub>It is generally impractical to have an employee without a department but this is just an example. Needless to mention that null foreign keys exist in other types of associations.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of Chapter 2.9 Entity Relationships of the [JPA 2.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)  is that it is not necessary since you have specified `orphanRemoval`. Here are the words of the spec:

> Associations that are specified as `OneToOne` or `OneToMany` support use
>   of the orphanRemoval option. The following behaviors apply when
>   orphanRemoval is in effect:
>
> - If an entity that is the target of the relationship is removed from the relationship (by setting the relationship to null or removing the
>     entity from the relationship collection), the remove operation will be
>     applied to the entity being orphaned. The remove operation is applied
>     at the time of the flush operation. The `orphanRemoval` functionality is
>     intended for entities that are privately "owned" by their parent
>     entity.  Portable applications must otherwise not depend upon a
>     specific order of removal, and must not reassign an entity that has
>     been orphaned to another relationship or otherwise attempt to persist
>     it. If the entity being orphaned is a detached, new, or removed
>     entity, the semantics of `orphanRemoval` do not apply.
> - If the remove operation is applied to a managed source entity, the remove operation will be cascaded to the relationship target in
>     accordance with the rules of section
>     3.2.3, (and hence it is not necessary to specify `cascade=REMOVE` for the relationship).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in asking this question, since I directly typed the example in the text editor and it was not taken from the real application. `CascadeType` and `orphanRemoval` are actually not specified on the inverse side (since `ON DELETE SET NULL` is specified in the back-end system). Editing the question now to remove them will change the definition of the question in its entirely. Perhaps, I will ask the same question by removing `CascadeType` and `orphanRemoval` from the inverse side.

Comment: In that case, I would expect that it is necessary to manually clear the relationship.

Comment: I'm using JPA pretty intensively for my current project. Your question intrigued me.